# How to wrap image with div in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x

To remove default wrap around image, i have used this template code:

```
tt_content.image.20.rendering.noWraps {
  imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  noRowsStdWrap.wrap = |
  oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  imgTagStdWrap.wrap = |
  editIconsStdWrap.wrap = |
  caption.wrap = |
}
# Set this as active rendering method
tt_content.image.20.renderMethod = noWraps
```

I want to override it above codes for a specific section.

Here is my code to do so:

```
SCREENSHOTS<styles.content.get
SCREENSHOTS.select.where = colPos = 9
SCREENSHOTS.renderObj.dataWrap = <div class="screen">|</div>
```

It doesn't work. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the CONTENT object](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#cobj-content-examples):

> Since in the above example .renderObj is not set explicitly, TYPO3 will automatically set 1.renderObj < **tt_content**, so that renderObj will reference the TypoScript configuration of **tt_content**. The according TypoScript configuration will be copied to renderObj.

Since you declare `SCREENSHOTS.renderObj.dataWrap = <div class="screen">|</div>` you properly wont have any configuration automatically copied to your `renderObj`.

If I understand your goal correct then you wish to remove all wraps around 'image only' content element and wrap it all in one div tag `<div class="screen">|</div>`. The following is untested but should work if your provided first code blocked worked for all your 'image only' content elements.

```
# Create a new renderMethod named 'noWraps' which can be used across the whole system
tt_content.image.20.rendering.noWraps {
  imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  noRowsStdWrap.wrap = |
  oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  imgTagStdWrap.wrap = |
  editIconsStdWrap.wrap = |
  caption.wrap = |
}

SCREENSHOTS < styles.content.get
SCREENSHOTS {
  select.where = colPos = 9
  renderObj < tt_content
  renderObj {
    # Set renderMethod to 'noWraps' only for this section
    image.20.renderMethod = noWraps

    # Change the default wrapping around the content element but only if it's a 'image only' contant element
    stdWrap.innerWrap >
    stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
    stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
      key.field = CType
      default < tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject
      image = TEXT
      image.value = <div class="screen">|</div>
    }
  }
}
```

If the above code dose not work then just write a comment and then I will take a look into it.