# I need to unwrap a TextPic CElement in TypoScript at a certain colPos

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to do exactly what I mentioned in the Title. I want to unwrap (redefine the output even if needed) a content element (textpic since I use it for a slider output) at a certain Col Position (defined in my Backend Layout).
I done it with Jquery, but this seemes to be a sub-par solution.

My Code:

```
tt_content = CASE 
tt_content {
key.field = colPos
#10 = CASE
10 {
    #key.field = CType
    stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject >
    stdWrap.innerWrap2 >
    dataWrap >
    prepend >
    textpic.20.text.10.10.stdWrap.dataWrap >
    image.20.imageStdWrap.dataWrap >
    image.20.imageStdWrapNoWidth.wrap >
    image.20.imageColumnStdWrap.dataWrap >
    image.20.layout.default.value = ###IMAGES######TEXT###
    image.20.layout.1.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.2.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.8.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.9.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.10.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.17.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.18.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.25.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.layout.26.value < image.20.layout.default.value
    image.20.rendering.dl.imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap >
    image.20.rendering.dl.oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap >
    image.20.rendering.dl.imgTagStdWrap.wrap >
    image.20.rendering.dl.editIconsStdWrap.wrap >
    image.20.rendering.dl.caption.wrap >
    textpic.20.text.10.10.stdWrap.dataWrap >
    textpic.20.text.wrap >
}
}
```

Anyone has an idea or even a snippet ? ;)

Thx alot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[I have answered a question similar this once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669848/how-to-wrap-image-with-div-in-typo3/32246696#32246696)

Instead of changing the entire tt_content configuration then just change it where you need it.

In below example I have created a new rendering method called 'noWraps' and in here i have cleared all the wraps.

Next I create a content lib `lib.yourContent`, you can name it as you like. We select the colPos we like, from your example we use `colPos = 10`. Then we explicitly tells renderObj to copy the tt_content configuration and next we override 'textpic' renderMethod to use 'noWraps'.

```
# Create a new renderMethod named 'noWraps' which can be used across the whole system
tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.noWraps {
  imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  noRowsStdWrap.wrap = |
  oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  imgTagStdWrap.wrap = |
  editIconsStdWrap.wrap = |
  caption.wrap = |
}

lib.yourContent < styles.content.get
lib.yourContent {
  select.where = colPos = 10
  renderObj < tt_content
  renderObj {
    # Set renderMethod to 'noWraps' only for this section
    textpic.20.renderMethod = noWraps
  }
}
```

Above code is still untested but it should work - just ask if it don't.

I can see that you also overrides the default layouts but you haven't mention that in your question? If you need to override this then just add/update the following.

```
lib.yourContent < styles.content.get
lib.yourContent {
  select.where = colPos = 10
  renderObj < tt_content
  renderObj {
    # Set renderMethod to 'noWraps' only for this section
    textpic.20.renderMethod = noWraps
    textpic.20.layout >
    textpic.20.layout = TEXT
    textpic.20.layout.value = ###IMAGES######TEXT###
  }
}
```

Since you in your own example just override all the different cases to the same value then we can just as well redefine it as a static value. First we use `textpic.20.layout >` to clear the default configuration. Then we define it as a TEXT object `textpic.20.layout = TEXT` and then at the end we set the value `textpic.20.layout.value = ###IMAGES######TEXT###`

## UPDATE: Below is tested and works with TYPO3 CMS 7.4.0

I have added some extra code to remove the last wraps.

```
# Create a new renderMethod named 'noWraps' which can be used across the whole system
tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.noWraps {
  imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  noRowsStdWrap.wrap = |
  oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = |
  imgTagStdWrap.wrap = |
  editIconsStdWrap.wrap = |
  caption.wrap = |
  allStdWrap.dataWrap = |
}

lib.yourContent < styles.content.get
lib.yourContent {
  select.where = colPos = 10
  renderObj < tt_content
  renderObj {
    # Set renderMethod to 'noWraps' only for this section
    textpic.20.renderMethod = noWraps
    textpic.20.imageStdWrap.dataWrap = |
    textpic.20.imageStdWrapNoWidth = |
    textpic.20.layout >
    textpic.20.layout = TEXT
    textpic.20.layout.value = ###IMAGES######TEXT###
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your long comment on this. I think it would work, but somehow I can't parse Data into my markers. (using css_styled_template), he doesn't know lib.slidercontent when I try to parse em.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correct - don't you get any output?
I have just tested above code and added some small modifications to remove some extra wraps - but it works

Comment: Thanks again for this epic solution, I think I will use this pretty often in the future. I figured it out, had a Bracket missing in my Typoscript. I hope Typo3 7 has a better debugging for Typoscript Backend Editor ;)

Comment: Hi Mark, glad i could help. would you please mark my answer as the correct answer so this question could be closed?